# How much should be revealed to the players when rolling gifts of the gods?

Tags: gm-techniques, black-crusade

Beginning on the page 290 of black crusade core rulebook is explained the gifts of the gods generation. Whenever a player reaches a certain corruption threshold, how much should be revelead about the whole procedure of rolling the gifts to the player? My players are not new to roleplaying, but some of them are new to 40k universe. One of them is very experienced on munchiness, but he has been holding bsck due to roleplaying.

Should one reveal everything, from theme to the full game mechanics or just the general names of the mutations when adjusting by the amount of infamy? Should the GM roll or the player?

in example: 34 is rolled on table 9-1: gifts of the gods (p. 291), and lets assume the character has 2 infamy points.

- Do I just hand the player the book?
- Reveal parts such as "your options are emaciated, eyes of chaos or eye stalks"?
- Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grabbing the Dark Crusade Core Rulebook and perusing Chapter 9: Corruption and Infamy (pg288), I read the following passage:

> As a character progresses through an ongoing campaign, he garners Corruption Points (CPs). Starting out at 0, these slowly rise until they eventually reach 100. At various points along the way the character earns the right to beseech the Ruinous Powers for their favor, or else he draws the unsought attention of one of the Dark Gods by his deeds alone. ***At that point, the character rolls on Table 9-1: Gifts of the Gods to determine which Gift of the Gods he has earned.*** But the powers of Chaos are often fickle, capricious, or downright cruel, and there is no guarantee the character will be gifted with a power he desired.

This makes me think that since the *character* rolls, the Players should make the rolls for their own character. I'm assuming that the Players all have access to the Core Rulebook at all times, such that if they wanted to look up the different possibilities on Table 9-1, they could. For this particular roll, however, knowing all the options means little since it's mechanically based on what you roll and if you have enough Infamy to alter the result.

This actually means quite a bit when tying in to your question. The Gift of the Gods is a 1d100 roll against Table 9-1, triggered by crossing a Corruption Point. The roll is the random part, but the Player potentially has a small amount of agency to affect the outcome. In order to effectively utilize their agency, they have to be able to have data available to them to weigh the pros and cons of a given decision.

Now, your main question was how you approach this situation with regards to how much information you convey to Players. Assuming they do NOT have full access to the Core Rulebook, I would describe and/or summarize the fluff side of the available options, and then if they're interested in the mechanics of a given choice, I essentially "give them the book" in that I offer all relevant mechanical information readily. I figure this will let the Player make the choice that most appeals to them for their Character, and thus increase the game's fun.